# Android RelativeLayout.setRotation containing ImageView image has angled edges

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout containing an ImageView or a TextView. I call:

```
relativeLayout.setRotation(8);
```

The ImageView and the TextView have angled edges, I would like to remove.

[Screen Image](http://www.adoubleu.de/files/Screen.png)

**What I have tried so far:**

Override all Layouts and Views to add:

```
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, 
        Paint.DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | 
        Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | 
        Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
    );
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your PaintFlagsDrawFilter to 1 instead of 0:

```
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(1, 
        Paint.DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | 
        Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | 
        Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
    );
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```